# ASP.NET MVC Music Store Questions

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4.1

in the mvc 3 music store example they do the following.

```
Public Class Album

Public Property GenreId AS Integer

...

Public Overidable Property Genre as Genre

End Class
```

Entity framework seems to be pretty slick and picks up that GenreId is the PK for the Genre table.  So the SQL table for "Album" has GenreId as a column and when we load the album storeDB.album.find(x) it will also load the "Genre" entity.

My question is, what if we wanted to have a second object of the same type.  so for example, what if each album had a primaryGenre and a secondaryGenre.  i would think that we could do something like this.

```
Public Class Album

Public Property MainGenreId As Integer
Public Overidable Property MainGenre As Genre

Public Property BackupGenreId As Integer
Public Overidable Property BackupGenre as Genre

End Class
```

and i have also tried this...

```
Public Class Album

Public Property MainGenre_GenreId As Integer
Public Overidable Property MainGenre As Genre

Public Property BackupGenre_GenreId As Integer
Public Overidable Property BackupGenre as Genre

End Class
```

however, none of these options are working properly. can anybody point me in the right direction such that when i load the album through storeDB.album.find(x) it will automatically populate the MainGenre and the BackupGenre?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either data annotations or Fluent API to configure the relationships. Assuming there are two collection properties named `MainGenreAlbums` and `BackupGenreAlbums` on `Genre` entity, you can use the `ForeignKey` and `InverseProperty` attributes to configure the relationships.

```
Public Class Album

  Public Property MainGenreId As Integer

  <ForeignKey("MainGenreId")>
  <InverseProperty("MainGenreAlbums")>
  Public Overidable Property MainGenre As Genre

  Public Property BackupGenreId As Integer

  <ForeignKey("BackupGenreId")>
  <InverseProperty("BackupGenreAlbums")>
  Public Overidable Property BackupGenre as Genre

End Class
```

Comment: excellent!! thank you, that worked perfectly.  i was trying to figure out the Fluent API but DA's are just fine.  i didnt use the "InverseProperty" because i dont really understand what that is, but it worked with just the ForeignKey pointing to the appropriate "Integer".  thanks again.